# mvc3 dropdown not working because of unicode character '\'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code, the page works unil I submit it and try and save to the db, I have the field as a  nvarchar(70). when I select the 'Fund/Investment Manager' and because of the '/' the page comes up with an error. I even tried using  *HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Fund-Investment Manager",....)* but that didn't work. Has anyone else come up with this issue before?
thanks in advance 
Hesh

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
       model => model.JobDesc, 
       new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = "Please Select" , text = "Please Select"  },
                   new { value = "Buy-Side Analyst" , text = "Buy-Side Analyst" },
                   new { value = "Fund/Investment Manager" , text = "Fund/Investment Manager"},
                   new { value = "Sell-Side Analyst" , text = "Sell-Side Analyst"},
                   new { value = "Broker" , text = "Broker"},
                   new { value = "Other" , text = "Other"}
                },
              "value",
              "text", new { @class = "chk" }
       )
    )
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Just for fun, try text = @"Fund/Investment Manager"

Answer (score 0):

have you tried escaping the string?

Fund//Investment Manager

Comment: Hi I everything you suggested - still the same.
the error i am getting is

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException', but this dictionary requires a model item of type. 
but for the other options it works fine its all because of the '/' character

thanks

Comment: Hi All Thanks for your help I managed to get it working. All I did was refresh the entity modal data and now it works.
Thanks again
Hesh